# How to modify a constructor of LogAnalyzer class to include an argument that calls to LogReader class?

Tags: java, bluej

First, I am aware that a similar question has been asked a few years ago but it doesn't appear to work for some reason or another. The code fragment compiles, yes, but it doesn't work as each time I try to execute the program, I run into this error

"java.lang.String can not be converted to LogfileReader."

I know what this error means but I do not know why this is happening and I don't have enough coding experience to figure it out on my own. Additionally, this is the first time that I have encountered having to use 'this' or an argument inside of a constructor (rather than an argument in a method) so I have no previous experience with it.

I have a theory that I need to include some sort of `LogfileReader reader = new LogfileReader(r);` but that also seems incorrect.

The objective is to create a LogfileAnalyzer object that then passes the name of a file that I create in LogfileCreator onto LogfileReader's constructor. I believe that this includes an instance of 'this' and the book implies that this can be done without any modifications to the class of LogfileReader.

This is the relevant bit of code in LogfileAnalyzer:

```
public class LogAnalyzer
{
// Where to calculate the hourly access counts.
private int[] hourCounts;
// Use a LogfileReader to access the data.
private LogfileReader reader;

/**
 * Create an object to analyze hourly web accesses.
 * Reads files created in LogfileCreator
 */
  public LogAnalyzer(LogfileReader r)
  {
     this.reader = r;
     hourCounts = new int[24];
  }
```

And it is based on a previous answered question of a similar nature.

After creating the file using LogfileCreator and typing in the string ("This Blog") into the prompt for LogfileAnalyzer(LogfileReader r), I end up with the String error above.

If this helps, this is the full code for the LogfileReader class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * A class to read information from a file of web server accesses.
 * Currently, the log file is assumed to contain simply
 * date and time information in the format:
 *
 *    year month day hour minute
 * Log entries are sorted into ascending order of date.
 * 
 * @author David J. Barnes and Michael Kölling.
 * @version    2016.02.29
 */
public class LogfileReader implements Iterator<LogEntry>
{
    // The data format in the log file.
    private String format;
    // Where the file's contents are stored in the form
    // of LogEntry objects.
    private ArrayList<LogEntry> entries;
   // An iterator over entries.
   private Iterator<LogEntry> dataIterator;

   /**
     * Create a LogfileReader to supply data from a default file.
     */
    public LogfileReader()
    {
        this("weblog.txt"); 
    }

    /**
     * Create a LogfileReader that will supply data
     * from a particular log file. 
     * @param filename The file of log data.
     */
    public LogfileReader(String filename)
    {
        // The format for the data.
        format = "Year Month(1-12) Day Hour Minute";
        // Where to store the data.
        entries = new ArrayList<>();

        // Attempt to read the complete set of data from file.
        boolean dataRead;
        try{
            // Locate the file with respect to the current environment.
            URL fileURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filename);
            if(fileURL == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException(filename);
            }
            Scanner logfile = new Scanner(new File(fileURL.toURI()));
            // Read the data lines until the end of file.
            while(logfile.hasNextLine()) {
                String logline = logfile.nextLine();
                // Break up the line and add it to the list of entries.
                LogEntry entry = new LogEntry(logline);
                entries.add(entry);
            }
            logfile.close();
            dataRead = true;
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException | URISyntaxException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem encountered: " + e);
            dataRead = false;
        }
        // If we couldn't read the log file, use simulated data.
        if(!dataRead) {
            System.out.println("Failed to read the data file: " + filename);
            System.out.println("Using simulated data instead.");
            createSimulatedData(entries);
        }
        // Sort the entries into ascending order.
        Collections.sort(entries);
        reset();
    }

    /**
     * Does the reader have more data to supply?
     * @return true if there is more data available,
     *         false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return dataIterator.hasNext();
    }

    /**
     * Analyze the next line from the log file and
     * make it available via a LogEntry object.
     * 
     * @return A LogEntry containing the data from the
     *         next log line.
     */
    public LogEntry next()
    {
        return dataIterator.next();
    }

    /**
     * Remove an entry.
     * This operation is not permitted.
     */
    public void remove()
    {
        System.err.println("It is not permitted to remove entries.");
    }

    /**
     * @return A string explaining the format of the data
     *         in the log file.
     */
    public String getFormat()
    {
        return format;
    }

    /**
     * Set up a fresh iterator to provide access to the data.
     * This allows a single file of data to be processed
     * more than once.
     */
    public void reset()
    {
        dataIterator = entries.iterator();
    }

    /**
     * Print the data.
     */    
    public void printData()
    {
        for(LogEntry entry : entries) {
            System.out.println(entry);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Provide a sample of simulated data.
     * NB: To simplify the creation of this data, no
     * days after the 28th of a month are ever generated.
     * @param data Where to store the simulated LogEntry objects.
     */
    private void createSimulatedData(ArrayList<LogEntry> data)
   {
        LogfileCreator creator = new LogfileCreator();
        // How many simulated entries we want.
        int numEntries = 100;
        for(int i = 0; i < numEntries; i++) {
            data.add(creator.createEntry());
        }
    }
}
```

Thank anyone who wants to help or assist. I apologize for my lack of knowledge. I feel like the answer is probably rather simple but I can't figure out.